# Im not able to access Response.Headers("Content-Disposition") on client even after enable CORS

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Im trying to retrieve the filename of an excel file that is generated in the backend (Asp.net Core 2.2) and as you can see in the c# code, the filename is retrieved in the header of the response but from the client I cannot access to the header 'Content Disposition'

As you can see on the print bellow, in spite of the Content disposition is not present in the headers, it is present in XHR response headers

log of response.headers
[image]

XHR
[image: t]

I already enable de CORS policy in the backend as you can see here:

Startup.cs (ConfigureServices method)

```
services
    .AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(CorsAllowAllOrigins,
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("*").WithHeaders("*").WithMethods("*"));
    })
    .AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(authorizationPolicy));
    })
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtSecurityOptions.SecretKey);

        options.Audience = jwtSecurityOptions.Audience;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
    })
```

Startup.cs(Configure method)

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseCors(CorsAllowAllOrigins);
app.UseMvc();
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet("{reportResultId}/exportExcelFile")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesErrorResponseType(typeof(void))]
[Authorize(Policy = nameof(RoleType.N1))]
public ActionResult ExportExcelFile(int reportResultId, [FromQuery]bool matchedRows, [FromQuery]ExportExcelType exportExcelType)
{
    var authenticatedUser = Request.GetAuthenticatedUser();
    var result = _reconciliationResultService.GetDataForExportExcelFile(reportResultId, matchedRows,authenticatedUser.UserName ,exportExcelType, authenticatedUser.UserName, authenticatedUser.Id);

    if (result != null)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(result.WorkbookContent);
        var contentType = new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, contentType)
        {
            FileDownloadName = result.FileName
        };

        fileStreamResult.FileDownloadName=result.FileName;

        return fileStreamResult;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

--------------Client ---------------------

Container.ts

```
exportExcelFile(matchedRows: string) {
    this._reportService.exportExcelFile(matchedRows, this.reportInfo.id, this.exportExcelType).subscribe((response) => {
        var filename = response.headers.get("Content-Disposition").split('=')[1]; //An error is thrown in this line because response.headers.get("Content-Disposition") is always null
        filename = filename.replace(/"/g, "")
        const blob = new Blob([response.body],
            { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });

        const file = new File([blob], filename,
            { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });

        this.exportingExcelFile = false;
        this.ready = true;
        saveAs(file);
    });
}
```

ReportService.ts

```
exportExcelFile(matchedRows: string, reportInfoId: number, exportExcelType:ExportExcelType): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${environment.apiUrls.v1}/reconciliationResult/${reportInfoId}/exportExcelFile?matchedRows=${matchedRows}&exportExcelType=${exportExcelType}`;
    return this.http.get(url, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' });
}
```

app.module.ts

````
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
import { ReportModule } from './report/report.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TopNavComponent } from './layout/topnav.component';
import { SideBarComponent } from './layout/sidebar.component';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { DynamicDialogModule } from 'primeng/dynamicdialog';
import { SharedModule } from './core/shared.module';
import { JwtInterceptor } from './core/_helpers/jwt.interceptor';
import { ErrorInterceptor } from './core/_helpers/error.interceptor';
import { LoginRoutingModule } from './login/login-routing.module';
import { LogingModule } from './login/login.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedModule,
    ReportModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DynamicDialogModule,
    LogingModule,
    LoginRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TopNavComponent,
    SideBarComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    DatePipe,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
     { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Note: I'm implementing JWT. I don't know if it can have any impact on the headers.
````

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your server needs to *expose* the header as part of its CORS configuration, using `WithExposedHeaders`. Here's an example:

```
services
    .AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(CorsAllowAllOrigins, builder => 
            builder.WithOrigins("*")
                   .WithHeaders("*")
                   .WithMethods("*")
                   .WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition"));
    });
```

This sets the [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) header.

Comment: Just a question, Why do wee need to Expose the heaser explicitly?
Shouldnt .WithHeaders("*") be enough?

Comment: `WithHeaders` is about headers that the client can send (i.e. request headers), but `WithExposedHeaders` is about headers that the client can receive (i.e. response headers).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use something like this before returning your response:

```
HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", YOUR_VALUE);
```

This way, each endpoint can have a custom header exposed, without updating Startup.cs.

Comment: In net6, you can use the available constants for more type safety, `Response.Headers.AccessControlExposeHeaders = HeaderNames.ContentDisposition;`